# Using Ajax and JSON to display PHP echo message in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ive been trying to connect my PHP file to my HTML file using Javascript/jQuery and json. When the user inputs a number into the input box in the form and submits it, the PHP file should multiply the number by two and send it back to the user.

However when I press the submit button it takes me to the php page instead of displaying the information (processed in the php file) in HTML.

This is my HTML form:

```
<div id="formdiv">
    <form action="phpfile.php" method="get" name="form1" id="form1" class="js-php">
    Mata in ett nummer: <input id="fill1" name="fill1" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is my Javascript file

```
$(".js-php").submit(function(e){

    var data = {
        "fill1"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + $.param(data); 

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        url:"phpfile.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (data){
            $("#formdiv").append("Your input: "+data)
            alert (data);
        }
    })

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

PHP file:

```
$kvantitet = $_GET['fill1'];
$y = 2; 
$work = $kvantitet * $y;
$bork = $work * $kvantitet;
echo json_encode($work) ."<br>"; 
echo json_encode($bork);
```

Comment: Why not just have the javascript multiply it?

Comment: There is no `js-php` class in the markup you've provided.

Comment: @Baruch I want to learn how to connect the echo statement from PHP to HTML.

Comment: Whoops my bad, will edit it in right now @JonStirling

Comment: Your problem is that the submit method is doing the GET, not the $.ajax, because you put `e.preventDefault();` at the end and not at the beginning of the submit method.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you could do a bit differently here to make this work:

Currently, using both [**`.serialize`**](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [**`$.param`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) your `data` variable contains something like this:

```
someurl.php?fill1=1&0=f&1=i&2=l&3=l&4=1&5=%3D&6=1
```

If you use only `.serialize` you will get something easier to work with:

```
?fill1=5
```

---

On the PHP side, currently your code outputs [something like this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc37c071e52b9d391831fc0b1afb6141af15bfa0):

```
4<br>8
```

By adding your values to an array you can get a response back that you can work with:

```
$result    = array();
$kvantitet = $_GET['fill1']; // Lets say this is 5
$y         = 2; 
$work      = $kvantitet * $y;
$bork      = $work * $kvantitet;

//add the values to the $result array
$result = array(
    "work" => $work,
    "bork" => $bork
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

[Which will output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8664773125f4894c8058bf623583878eb7acde47):

```
{"work":4,"bork":8}
```

---

Back on the JS side you can then handle the data in your success callback:

```
$(".js-php").submit(function(e){
    data = $(this).serialize(); 
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"json",
        url:"phpfile.php",
        data: data,
        success: function (data){
            // *data* is an object - {"work":4,"bork":8}
            $("#formdiv").append("Your input: "+data)
            console(data);
        }
    });
    // Use return false to prevent default form submission
    return false;
});
```

One way to access the properties in your object is by using dot notation:

```
data.work //Outputs 4
data.bork //Outputs 8
```

But [here is a really great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) on processing / accessing objects and arrays using JavaScript.

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdoye/gxok5dux/4/) containing your (working) jQuery

Comment: Hello M.Doye, I feel like I'm making a lot of progress, however I still unable to get the echo message from PHP to show up in HTML like you did on your example on jsfiddle. Here is what I've done so far: (not very good at using jsfiddle yet)


https://jsfiddle.net/mdoye/gxok5dux/4/

Comment: @PHPScrub  Use the network inspector in your browser developer console to make sure the request is being sent as you expect it to - also, you will need to update the fiddle. (the one you posted is the same one I posted)

Comment: Ive tried it. Request is being sent. But it redirects me to the PHP file regardless of what I try.

Comment: Sounds like it could be the form, try it this way, without the actual form - https://jsfiddle.net/mdoye/gxok5dux/6/

Comment: @PHPScrub I left out a semi-colon after the ajax call, that could have been causing your issue, have updated the Fiddle and answer

Comment: It doesnt work on my webbrowser, only on Jsfiddle unfortunately. I've also tried replacing "/echo/json/" with the php file name but it still doesnt work...

Comment: When I follow this example my "data" becomes a string I think and not an object, data.work gives "undefined". I have to do "var object = JSON.parse(data)" and then "object.work". Why is that?

Comment: @David would need to see your code to answer accurately, perhaps best if you [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) specific to your issue

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting JSON Data but what you send back is not JSON

Try output the following in your PHP File:

```
$data['work'] = $work;

$data['bork'] = $bork;

echo json_encode( (object)$data );
```

Use console.log to inspect incoming data on the AJAX call then handle it according to how you want.

Comment: Just a note that the `(object)` cast is not needed due to string keys.

Comment: yes is not necessary for string keys, but for me I usually like to make it as an object before doing the encode

Answer (score 0):

I think you need &

```
data = $(this).serialize()+'&'+$.param(data);
```

and as @leonardo_palma mentioned in comments maybe you need to use `e.preventDefault();` in the beginning  of submit function

and I prefer to use

```
$(document).on('submit','.js-php',function(){/*code here*/});
```